# Get palindrome length from string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one string as "testaabbaccc" in this string we contain palindrome as "abba" and it's length is 4 but how can we identify this with a JavaScript code.

```
 var string ="testaabbaccc"
```

Need Output as abba is palindrome and length is 4

Comment: The length is trivial, the real question is how do you identify a palindrome in an arbitrary string? So what have you done to solve your homework question? I see no effort on your part.

Comment: You may wish to review [ask] - it will provide you with some tips on how to formulate your questions.  A well-formed question is critical to getting useful guidance from the community.  Good luck!

Comment: check for repetition of letter i.e.,string start with t then check for t in the entire string if yes split string and check for palindrome..... Show some work that you have tried with...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this [article](https://www.codementor.io/tips/1943378231/find-longest-palindrome-in-a-string-with-javascript) and modify it to your needs.

**Working demo**

```js
function isPalindrome(s) {
  var rev = s.split("").reverse().join("");
  return s == rev;
}
function longestPalind(s) {
  var maxp_length = 0,
    maxp = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    var subs = s.substr(i, s.length);
    for (var j = subs.length; j >= 0; j--) {
      var sub_subs = subs.substr(0, j);
      if (sub_subs.length <= 1)
        continue;
      if (isPalindrome(sub_subs)) {
        if (sub_subs.length > maxp_length) {
          maxp_length = sub_subs.length;
          maxp = sub_subs;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return maxp;
}

console.log(longestPalind("testaabbaccc"));
console.log(longestPalind("testaabbaccc").length);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Also need to get that abba part of an string is an palindrome

Comment: @miteshjain Have you checked the demo? it returns both `abba` and `4`